# Is there a way to have a Pyinstaller GUI reference a shared folder with other GUIs in order to reduce the redundant library files on disk

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have two similar GUIs that use the same libraries (PyQT5, numpy, matlibplot) and was wondering if there was a way to have each GUI folder only contain the unique files and to have a shared folder contain the identical files

Basically what I have now

```
--Main Folder
   --GUI_A 
     --GUI_libraries
   --GUI_B 
     --GUI_libraries
```

And want I'd like

```
--Main Folder
   --GUI_libraries
   --GUI_A(able to reference GUI_libraries)
   --GUI_B(able to reference GUI_libraries)
```

I am not using --onefile so each GUI is currently a folder containing its necessary files and the executable.

Comment: What do you mean with "two similar GUIs"? Are those two programs that will have a distinct package for each one?

Comment: Both GUI are built with the exact same libraries and imports. Their .spec files are identical other than one calls GUIA and one calls GUIB. Aesthetically they look different but contain the exact same components

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking but, wouldn't it be easier if you just create a single package and provide an option (on startup or by providing a common "switcher" window) to choose which one to use?

Comment: I'd like to scale this to many GUIs so a tab system wouldn't work

Comment: I never mentioned tabs. If the GUIs are almost identical and they just look different, then provide a simple dialog window on start up (possibly callable from some menu or button) in order to choose which one to use, possibly with something like a "remember choice/don't ask anymore" checkbox. From what I know, pyinstaller has to put all contents inside a *child* folder in order to correctly work with its libraries, and I sincerely doubt that what you're asking is possible (but I can be wrong), unless you use a common installation path for both and only differentiate executables.

Comment: That wouldn't fit my project, but thanks for the suggestion. I will look more into the file path dependencies for pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Believe the multipackaging functionality in PyInstaller will let me keep one set of libraries for a top level GUI and have subsequent GUIs reference to those libraries, rather than having multiple local copies of the same libraries.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles